# static linking not providing code in gdb of library api strlen() and puts()

Tags: c, gdb, disassembly

I am linking code statically and its 3 line code and after static linkage i am going through disassembled code but while listing i am not getting library api strlen() and puts().

```
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x00000000004004b4 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x00000000004004b5 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000004004b8 <+4>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x00000000004004bc <+8>:     movq   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x00000000004004c4 <+16>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000000004004c8 <+20>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x00000000004004cb <+23>:    callq  0x4016c0 <puts>
   0x00000000004004d0 <+28>:    leaveq
   0x00000000004004d1 <+29>:    retq

(gdb) disassemble puts
Dump of assembler code for function puts:
=> 0x00000000004016c0 <+0>:     mov    %rbx,-0x18(%rsp)
   0x00000000004016c5 <+5>:     mov    %rbp,-0x10(%rsp)
   0x00000000004016ca <+10>:    mov    %rdi,%rbp
   0x00000000004016cd <+13>:    mov    %r12,-0x8(%rsp)
   0x00000000004016d2 <+18>:    sub    $0x18,%rsp
   0x00000000004016d6 <+22>:    callq  0x40b870 <strlen>
   0x00000000004016db <+27>:    mov    0x2a816e(%rip),%r8        # 0x6a9850 <stdout>
   0x00000000004016e2 <+34>:    mov    %rax,%r12
   0x00000000004016e5 <+37>:    cmpw   $0x0,(%r8)
   0x00000000004016ea <+42>:    mov    %r8,%rbx
   0x00000000004016ed <+45>:    js     0x401740 <puts+128>
   0x00000000004016ef <+47>:    mov    0x88(%r8),%rdx
   0x00000000004016f6 <+54>:    mov    %fs:0x10,%r9
   0x00000000004016ff <+63>:    cmp    %r9,0x8(%rdx)
   0x0000000000401703 <+67>:    je     0x40173c <puts+124>

(gdb) list
1       #include <stdio.h>
2       int
3       main()
4       {
5           char *p = NULL;
6           printf("%s\n", p);
7       }
(gdb) q
```

It always displays my code and not library api even when i have kept breakpoint inside puts()/strlen().

Comment: What do you mean? that's the assembly for the puts function there - however, I guess the function doesn't even have debugging information, nor do you have source code for the libc

Comment: Also, my strlen *is* written in assembler - `106     ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S: No such file or directory.`

Comment: I have compiled using -ggdb so it should have debugging information. As per my understanding If i link statically it should have source code for libc. If i do not build statically, it does not even disassemble puts() or strlen().

Answer (score 2):

> I have compiled using -ggdb so it should have debugging information.

You have built *your* code with `-ggdb`. You have not rebuilt `libc.a` core with `-ggdb`, so `strlen` doesn't have debug info.

> As per my understanding If i link statically it should have source code for libc

Your understanding is incorrect. *Only* code that has been built with `-ggdb` (i.e. the code you rebuilt) gets debug info.